# Drawing a graph where nodes are graphs?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-graphs

I'd like to draw a circular (complete) graph, where the nodes are themselves graphs. I'm basically trying to draw a model of a minor for a certain graph, in a circular way, so that the subgraphs at each node are also circular.

If someone could point me to some code that draws a complete graph, where the nodes themselves are complete graphs, that would be perfect.

Comment: There are `pic`s, which are made for this. Alternatively you may use the `path picture` option of nodes. You may also store the smaller graphs in `\savebox`es and use them in the bigger graph. Do yo have examples for the graphs?

Answer (score 3):

Welcome! This is an example of a graph in which the nodes are again graphs.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs, graphs.standard} 
\newsavebox\SmallGraph
\sbox\SmallGraph{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8,transform shape]
  \graph { a -> {b, c} -> d };
\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\graph[nodes={draw, circle}, clockwise, radius=.5cm,typeset=\usebox\SmallGraph, n=5] {
subgraph I_n [name=inner,radius=3cm] --[complete bipartite]
subgraph I_n [name=outer,radius=6cm] };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This is really helpful